# Migrating to EntityFramework 5 - NotMapped attribute in base class throwing exception

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am migrating an application from Entity Framework June 2011 CTP to Entity Frameowrk 5 (.net 4.5). I removed all the EF references for June 2011 CTP and added those for EF 5 in Visual Studio 2012. After fixing a few namespace errors, the application compiled fine. But I am getting an exception when I try to run the application and access the data. The exception occurs because of **NotMapped Attribute** that I have in my base entity class. Here are the relevant entities (Base and Derived).

**Base Entity Class**

```
[Table("Users")]
[Serializable]
public abstract class User {
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // Other Properties omitted

    [NotMapped]
    public string StringVersion {

    }
}
```

**Derived Entity Class**

```
[Table("Donors")]
[Serializable]
public class Donor : User {
    ...
}
```

When the application tries to access data, InvalidOperationException is thrown with the following message

```
You cannot use Ignore method on the property 'StringVersion' on type 'Donor' because 
this type inherits from the type 'User' where this property is mapped. To exclude 
this property from your model, use NotMappedAttribute or Ignore method on the base type.
```

I tried to solve the issue based on the workaround described at http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/481, but the Exception is still thrown. Specifically, I used the following code so that User is discovered before the Donor Entity.

```
public class DonorContext : DbContext {

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        //Change for EF 5 
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
        //

        //Other Fluent API code follows
    } 
}
```

How do I get around this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get it working by commenting the **NotMapped** attribute in the User (base) Entity, and instead using the **Fluent API Ignore** as given below.

```
public class DonorContext : DbContext {

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        //Added for EF 5 
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(u => u.StringVersion);
    }
}
```

Since I have only a few NotMapped attributes for Inherited Entities, I can get away with the above workaround. I hope Ignore behavior is same as NotMapped, and using one in place of other does not cause any issues.